# Why is the facebook pixel counting event conversions wrong?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have installed a FB pixel to track conversion events.  FB tools verify that it is set up right.  The results are dramatically inaccurate to the point that it basically isn't working.  We track events such as a user entering a phone number, etc.  We used FB JS code exactly as provided.  We compared our own results, measured directly by incrementing a counter using javascript every time an event fires, with those tracked on FB, and the results are dramatically different (e.g. off by >50%).  In addition, the results for this event are very inconsistent within FB itself depending on where in the FB UI you look.  If you look at the analytics event tester you see one number, on the pixel page a different one, on the ads manager a different one.  The differences are large (e.g. factor of >2x).

In order to test this we made the simplest possible html page using the FB pixel code directly from FB.  I have pasted it below.  Using this code (with our actual pixel id of course), and the FB 'Event Debugging' feature, we see no pixel fires.  Using the FB Pixel Helper in Chrome, it finds the pixel and the events just fine.  We tried loading the page in several different browsers on different machines.

What is going on?

Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://eg.com/favicon.png"/>
  <title>Pixel Tester</title>
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        fbq('track', 'PageView');
        fbq('trackCustom', 'test');
    </script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript></head>
<body>
Pixel-Tester
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your bounty description looks like you want people to do your job

Answer (score 2):

The difference between data in the ads manager and the pixel screen (facebook.com/ads/manager/pixel/facebook_pixel/) is due to the fact that, in the ads manager, you only see conversion associated with your campaigns. In the pixel screen, you see anytime the pixel, and the events connected to the pixel, are fired, no matter if it happened due to a Facebook campaign or not.